# How can I scale my image down with the size of the screen in html/css, or is scaling even the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, image

I have done this many times before, but I cannot seem to find the issue. The page is fine at a certain size, but once I start testing it out and scaling down to around 1260px width, the image starts to overflow and white space is created. I removed one of the column divs so the image was moved, and I could scale smaller before the white started to do this, but then part of my footer did the same thing. I know this likely has something to do with the @media queries, but things just got a little messy along the way and I had to take a break from the project. Can anybody point out what is going on?

Thanks.

[Here is an image showing the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1pIt.png)

[Here is an image showing correct scaling and alignment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M8oX.jpg)

I provided as much HTML as I could (the chunk with the image), without going over character limit.
And I have provided my entire CSS file below that.

```css
iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,
pre, a, abbr, acronym, big, cite,
code, del, dfn, em, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b,
u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset,
form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody,
tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside,
canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, output, ruby,
section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, , figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

mark {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input, select, textarea {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

/* Basic */

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
}

body.is-preload *, body.is-preload *:before, body.is-preload *:after {
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}

body, input, select, textarea {
    color: #666;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.65em;
}

a {
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: -webkit-link;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

strong, b {
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 400;
}

em, i {
    font-style: italic;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
    line-height: 1.35em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.35em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.35em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

/* Container */

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 4em);
    width: 60em;
}

.container.xsmall {
    width: 15em;
}

.container.small {
    width: 30em;
}

.container.medium {
    width: 45em;
}

.container.large {
    width: 75em;
}

.container.xlarge {
    width: 90em;
}

.container.max {
    width: 100%;
}

.address {
    color: #2e3842;
    position: fixed;
}

.phone {
    float: right;
    font-size: x-large;
}

#tree-climber {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {

    .container {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .container {
        max-width: calc(100% - 3em);
    }
    
    .img {
        width: fit-content;
        display: block;
    }

}

/* Row */

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.row > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.row > .col-4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}


.row > .col-6 {
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: -2em;
}

.row > * {
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}

.row.gtr-uniform {
    margin-top: -2em;
}

.row.gtr-uniform > * {
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.row.gtr-150 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: -3em;
}

.row.gtr-150 > * {
    padding: 0 0 0 3em;
}

/* Section/Article */

section.special, article.special {
    text-align: center;
}

header p {
    color: #999;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    position: relative;
}

header h2 + p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -1em;
}

header h3 + p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
}

header h4 + p,
header h5 + p,
header h6 + p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -0.6em;
}

header.major {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

header.major:after {
    background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.5);
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    width: 6em;
}

header.major h2, header.major h3, header.major h4, header.major h5, header.major h6 {
    margin: 0;
}


/* Image */

.image {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.image img {
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;

}

.image.left {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1.5em 1em 0;
    top: 0.25em;
}

.image.right {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 1em 1.5em;
    top: 0.25em;
}

.image.left, .image.right {
    max-width: 40%;
}

.image.left img, .image.right img {
    width: 100%;
}

.image.fit {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.image.fit img {
    width: 100%;
}

/* List */

ol {
    list-style: decimal;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    padding-left: 1.25em;
}

ol li {
    padding-left: 0.25em;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

ul li {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

ul.alt {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.alt li {
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.5);
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}

ul.alt li:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

dl {
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

/* Actions */

ul.actions {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    cursor: default;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -1em;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.actions li {
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.actions.special {
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}

ul.actions.special li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

/* Button */

input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"],
button,
.button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: floralwhite;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.5);
    color: #555 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 2.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0.125em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    padding: 0 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 0.125em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

input[type="submit"].wide,
input[type="reset"].wide,
input[type="button"].wide,
button.wide,
.button.wide {
    min-width: 12em;
}


input[type="submit"].disabled, input[type="submit"]:disabled,
input[type="reset"].disabled,
input[type="reset"]:disabled,
input[type="button"].disabled,
input[type="button"]:disabled,
button.disabled,
button:disabled,
.button.disabled,
.button:disabled {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.25;
}

/* Main */

.main {
    padding: 6em 0 4em 0;
}

.main.style1 {
    background: #2e3842;
}

.main.style2 {
    background-color: #333;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    }

.main.style2 a {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.main.style2 a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.main.style2 h1, .main.style2 h2, .main.style2 h3, .main.style2 h4, .main.style2 h5, .main.style2 h6, .main.style2 strong, .main.style2 b {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.main.style2 header p {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.main.style2 header.major:after {
    background: #ffffff;
}


.main.style2 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.main.style2 input[type="reset"]:hover,
.main.style2 input[type="button"]:hover,
.main.style2 button:hover,
.main.style2 .button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
}

.main.style2 input[type="submit"]:active,
.main.style2 input[type="reset"]:active,
.main.style2 input[type="button"]:active,
.main.style2 button:active,
.main.style2 .button:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.main.style2 input[type="submit"].primary,
.main.style2 input[type="reset"].primary,
.main.style2 input[type="button"].primary,
.main.style2 button.primary,
.main.style2 .button.primary {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff !important;
    color: #333 !important;
}

.main.style2 input[type="submit"].primary:hover,
.main.style2 input[type="reset"].primary:hover,
.main.style2 input[type="button"].primary:hover,
.main.style2 button.primary:hover,
.main.style2 .button.primary:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.main.style2 ul.major-icons li .icon {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}

.main.style2 .icon.major {
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Header */

#header {
    padding: 20em 0 9em 0;
    background-color: #4686a0;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed, fixed;
    background-image: url('/static/images/tree-stump-pile.webp');
    background-position: top left, center center, center center;
    background-size: auto, cover, cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#header a {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: inherit;
}

#header a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#header h1, #header h2, #header h3, #header h4, #header h5, #header h6, #header strong, #header b {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#header header p {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#header header.major:after {
    background: #ffffff;
}


#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

#header p {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

#header .actions {
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#header .actions li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#header .actions:after {
    background: #ffffff;
    content: '';
    height: 100vh;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}

#header .inner {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
    transition: transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#header .inner .actions {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.25s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1.25s ease;
    transition: transform 1.25s ease;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

#header:after {
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body.is-preload #header .inner {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    opacity: 0;
}

body.is-preload #header .inner .actions {
    -moz-transform: translateY(30em);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30em);
    -ms-transform: translateY(30em);
    transform: translateY(30em);
    opacity: 0;
}

body.is-preload #header:after {
    opacity: 1;
}



/*Logo*/

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 0;
}

/* Navbar */

.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;

}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
/* Footer */

.site-footer
{
  background-color:#26272b;
  padding:45px 0 20px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:24px;
  color:#737373;
}
.site-footer hr
{
  border-top-color:#bbb;
  opacity:0.5
}
.site-footer hr.small
{
  margin:20px 0
}
.site-footer h6
{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px
}
.site-footer a
{
  color:#737373;
}
.site-footer a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links
{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style:none
}
.footer-links li
{
  display:block
}
.footer-links a
{
  color:#737373
}
.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links.inline li
{
  display:inline-block
}
.site-footer .social-icons
{
  text-align:right
}
.site-footer .social-icons a
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right:0;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:#33353d
}
.copyright-text
{
  margin:0
}
@media (max-width:991px)
{
  .site-footer [class^=col-]
  {
    margin-bottom:30px
  }
}
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .site-footer
  {
    padding-bottom:0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,.site-footer .social-icons
  {
    text-align:center
  }
}
.social-icons
{
  padding-left:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  list-style:none
}
.social-icons li
{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:4px
}
.social-icons li.title
{
  margin-right:15px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#96a2b2;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:13px
}
.social-icons a{
  background-color:#eceeef;
  color:#818a91;
  font-size:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:44px;
  width:44px;
  height:44px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:8px;
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
  -o-transition:all .2s linear;
  transition:all .2s linear
}

/* XLarge */

@media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {

    /* Basic */
    body, input, select, textarea {
        font-size: 14pt;
    }

    /* Header */
    #header {
        padding: 6em 0 6em 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<!-- Two -->
<section id="two" class="main style2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row gtr-150">
            <div class="col-6 col-12-medium">
                <header class="major">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor adipiscing<br/>
                        amet dolor consequat</h2>
                </header>
                <p>Adipiscing a commodo ante nunc accumsan interdum mi ante adipiscing. A nunc lobortis non nisl
                    amet
                    vis volutpat aclacus nascetur ac non. Lorem curae eu ante amet sapien in tempus ac.
                    Adipiscing
                    id
                    accumsan adipiscing ipsum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-12-medium imp-medium">

                <img class="tree-climber" src="{% static 'images/PNW-diagonal-tree-climber.webp' %}"
                             alt="Image of tree climber">
                    </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `*` instead of this `iframe, h1, h2...`

Comment: In the code that you provided, your img tag has a class, but the CSS uses an ID, so the rule isn’t being applied, and the column rules don’t seem to be fully present (col-6 is always 100% of the width and col-12-medium has no rule). If you’re using a framework, can you include the CSS link?

Comment: Rich, your comment about the column rules, combined with the other person's answer helped a ton. All I did was remove the col-12-medium from the class, reload, and I am able to scale down the size and the white space is gone. Now it's just trying to optimize for mobile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

On the code bellow you selected the image using the id selector:

```
#tree-climber {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

But here you defined as a class:

```
<img class="tree-climber" src="{% static 'images/PNW-diagonal-tree-climber.webp' %}" alt="Image of tree climber">
</img>
```

Because of this your styling is not working.
You just have to use the class selector:

```
.tree-climber {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: In combination with what another person suggested, your solution did help. I appreciate it.